# View in select statement and return result

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to put a view in a select query i.e select name, ViewName(parameter) from sometable

I cannot seem to find anything on how to do this

Comment: `ViewName(Parameter)` doesn't make sense, a view doesn't take parameters, it must be used like a table, not like a scalar function

Comment: Maybe instead of a view you need an inline table valued function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do can be accomplished with a subquery.  In the below example (Taken from microsoft's website), Adventureworks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail can be a view and you can specify your 'parameter' in there where statement.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT Ord.SalesOrderID, Ord.OrderDate,
    (SELECT MAX(OrdDet.UnitPrice)
     FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS OrdDet
     WHERE Ord.SalesOrderID = OrdDet.SalesOrderID) AS MaxUnitPrice
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Ord
```